# I am trying to load data into r and am not sure what this error is referring to

Tags: r

I am trying to read a file into r and I keep getting this error. All of my libraries are installed and loaded. It is a spreadsheet with 2 sheets and I only want data from the second sheet.

```
read.xlsx(dataUrl, sheet = 2)
```

---

```
Error in getChildlessNode(xml = workbookRelsXML, tag = "Relationship") : 
  function 'Rcpp_precious_remove' not provided by package 'Rcpp'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the `Rcpp` package first:

```
install.packages('Rcpp')
library('Rcpp')
read.xlsx(dataUrl, sheet = 2)
```